# RegEX: need to block all backslashes and leave a forwardslash at the end

Tags: regex, qregexp

I need to pass strings like:

```
/test/
```

Some illegal things would be:

```
\test\
\test
/test
```

Comment: valid examples would be:
C:/test/
./test/
C:/Test/

it has to end with a forward slash and only contain forward slashes no backslashes at all...

Comment: found what the problem was: I must use 4 backslashes for it to work... ^[^\\\\]+$

Answer (score 1):

Something like this should match your strings.

```
^/.*/$
```

So that regex expects a the string to start and end with a forward slash and can have anything in between.

Comment: Note that `.*` would permit no characters to appear between the slashes. It would also allow one or more `/` characters to appear. Also, the `/` characters in the pattern may need to be escaped (depending on the language in which the regex is being interpreted).

Comment: @DavidRR He didn't say anything about what strings are valid. I agree with escaping the / (he didn't say in which context he's using them either, but you're right).

Comment: Do you think that `/te/st/` should be allowed? My hunch given his examples is probably not. But yes, this is an educated guess.

Comment: @DavidRR I really can't tell, that's why I assumed anything is valid. Maybe he wants to have urls between slashes, I don't know...That's why I gave the minimum expression that matches what he asked. He can then replace the .* for whatever he needs.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to allow only lower-case alphabetic characters between the slash characters, try this:

```
^\/[a-z]+\/$
```

**Explanation:**

```
^      require match to start at the very beginning of the string
\      escape the forward slash in the input string
[a-z]  the character class representing the set of lower case characters
+      the preceding character or character class occurs one or more times
$      require match to end at the very end of the string
```

---

**Edit:** When I answered this question, I confess to probably not noticing the [qregexp](/questions/tagged/qregexp) tag among the four tags originally on the question. Some regex parsers (such as that provided by Perl) require that a [delimiter character](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5004642/1497596) be used to designate the start and end of a pattern. For such regex parsers, the forward slash `/` is commonly used as a delimiter character. If that is the case, it is necessary to escape a `/` that appears in the regex pattern.

A question has been raised if it is necessary to escape a `/` that appears in a regex pattern to be processed by `qregexp`. Perhaps not–I'll leave that to be answered by the `qregexp` experts. That said, for regexp parsers that do *not* required a `/` to be escaped, the escape character `\` can be dropped from the pattern that I show above:

```
^/[a-z]+/$
```

Finally, if a particular regex might be used in more than one environment, it [doesn't hurt](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9226876/1497596) to escape a character that might be deemed special in one of those environments.

Comment: Do you really need to escape the `/` character in a QRegExp?

Comment: @AlexisWilke: Thanks for your feedback. Please see my edit.